# __doPostBack is not defined for mobile site only

Tags: mobile, sitecore

I am getting error "__doPostBack is not defined error" while using asp:LinkButton on mobile site that is based on "JqyeryMobile". I am not getting this error on desktop site.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="blue-button" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" data-ajax="false">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
```

and also I have javascript validation for this as below

```
    ('.blue-button').click(function () {
      // javascript code
    }
```

I have tried many solutions but not working for me. Can you please tell me that whether this is "JqueryMobile" problem or anything else?

Comment: "__doPostBack" is used by Asp.Net/Webforms and to handle form submissions. It should be included automatically when you add any server control... make sure `<form runat="server"></form>` is present on your mobile site if you are using a different layout

Comment: yeah it has runat="server" already, but not working.

Comment: I just saw page source (ctrl+U), and saw that 
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" /> 
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}

these 3 are not creating. Its working on my local but not creating on our dev environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enable caching on the sublayouts for your mobile site? This can interfere with the _dopostback, as seen in this question: [Sitecore: Turning on HTML Caching blocks postback behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628185/sitecore-turning-on-html-caching-blocks-postback-behavior)

This could also be an issue with the browser definitions in your version of .NET. If the browser you are using is unknown to .NET, it acts as if the device does not understand Javascript: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/javascript-referenceerror-cant-find-variable-__dopostback/

Comment: No, din't enable caching for this control. Actually its working for my local environment but not for dev envi..strange!

Comment: It was cashing issue. One of my control has cache, thats why it was creating problem.